# C++ Fixed size container with swappable elements

Tags: c++, stl, containers

I'm searching for a container with the following functionality:

- Fixed size at runtime. Thus, memory shouldn't be allocated in little chunks (like `std::list` does).
- Elements should be swappable (Something like `std::list::splice` offers).

**EDIT:**
Thinking of a list: I just need to move elements from an arbitrary position to the front.
EDIT2:
I would like to use something like a `std::list`, but takes advantage of a runtime fixed size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not too clear to me what you are looking for.  Two solutions come to mind: `std::vector` (created with the maximum size), coupled with a good implementation of `swap` for your objects, or a custom allocator for `std::list`, which pre-allocates the number of nodes you'll need in a single block.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The easiest way would be to use a custom `allocator`.

Comment: on that front, boost has a pool allocator specifically for lists, may be worth looking into.

Comment: @Nim - Thanks for your advice. I've tested the performance of `boost::pool_alloc` (exclusive deallocation) compared to a custom implementation of myself. The `boost` seems to be nice in suitable situations, but in my scenario my own one is much faster.

Answer (score 3):

I'd think of TR1 array:

```
std::array<T, int>
```

Or, if you haven't got that yet,

```
boost::array<T, int>
```

Which is identical for all intents and purposes. Of course the validity of std::swap on elements depends on availability of proper copy constructor/assignment operator.

Comment: `boost::array<T, int>` has compile time size. Furthermore, I would like to use something similar to a list, because I don't want to copy the elements.

Comment: Sorry; if you want to reduce allocations, [`std::vector::resize`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/resize/) is your friend. There are appropriate guarantees with regards to not re-allocating unless the need arises

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the (initial) size of an `std::list` at construction time :

```
std::list<Type> myList = std::list<Type>(10);
```

You can still grow/shrink it afterwards, but the list will contain 10 default constructed Type objects from the start.

Does that suit your needs ?

Comment: `std::list` fragments memory too much for my purpose.

Comment: @FrEEzE2046 : then using a custom allocator (as suggested elsewhere) could achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

std::vector ?

Array based. Can specify the size and has a swap function.

You haven't said what you'll be using it for so I don't really know if you're going to have any speed issues with it.